# Why a GET request send 2 requests to the ServerSocket.accept()?

Tags: java

My goal is to understand how a request works. My current knowledge is that, for every request, there is a preflight request. In other words, if you send a GET request, it will send a preflight request first, and then send the actual request after receiving response from the server.

My expected result: I can send a GET request from Postman, or at least I can see the OPTIONS request in the browser, but I can't seem find it.

My actual result: I can't send a GET request from Postman, but I can get the response from browser (after 2nd attempt, if you restart the `HttpServer.main()`, the "Hello World" somehow will show up, and then if you send the request again from browser, it will refuse to connect, rinse and repeat)

What I've did: I modify the code to keep accepting connection with `while(serverSocket.isBound() && !serverSocket.isClosed()) { //... until before the serverSocket.close(); }`. The LOGGER log 2 connection request when I send the request from browser and from Postman, but it works.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class HttpServer {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpServer.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LOGGER.info("Server starting...");
    try {
      ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080);
      Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

      LOGGER.info("* Connection accepted: " + socket.getInetAddress());

      InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
      OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();

      final String CRLF = "\r\n"; // 13 10

      String messageBody = "Hello World";

      // RFC2616 Section 6 Response
      // response = Status-Line +
      //            * ((general-header
      //               | response-header
      //               | entity-header) + CRLF) +
      //             CRLF +
      //             [ message-body ]
      String response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" + CRLF + // Status-Line = HTTP-Version SP Status-Code SP Reason-Phrase CRLF
              "Content-Length: " + messageBody.getBytes().length + CRLF + // end of entity-header fields
              CRLF + // end of Header Fields
              messageBody;

      outputStream.write(response.getBytes());
      LOGGER.info("Connection processing finished");
      inputStream.close();
      outputStream.close();
      socket.close();
      serverSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

This is the output I get when I use `while(serverSocket.isBound() && !serverSocket.isClosed()) { // ... until before the serverSocket.close(); }`

```
03:17:05.514 [main] INFO HttpServer - Server starting...
03:17:10.786 [main] INFO HttpServer - * Connection accepted: /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
03:17:10.789 [main] INFO HttpServer - Connection processing finished
03:17:10.955 [main] INFO HttpServer - * Connection accepted: /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
03:17:10.955 [main] INFO HttpServer - Connection processing finished
```

I also tried to log the `inputStream.read()`. I am assuming this should send  the preflight request, but instead it send the actual request right away.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
sec-ch-ua: " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Microsoft Edge";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36 Edg/91.0.864.41
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

Comment: "for every request, there is a preflight request" - where did you learn that? That's not the normal way that [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) works. Normally there is just one GET request, and no such thing as a "preflight request".

Comment: Are you talking about CORS? These have preflight requests to check what the server allows regarding CORS.

Comment: @Jesper there most definitely is such a thing. It’s a CORS thing!

Comment: I've coded a few REST services and do not know what you might mean by a "preflight request".   Could you be talking about TCP connection setup?  About TLS negotiation?  There are at least 3 levels of abstraction you could be confusing here.

Comment: @BoristheSpider- thanks for shedding some light on that!

Comment: @iggy I would imagine the servers you coded either don’t support CORS. Or the framework you used handles preflight requests automatically.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thanks - [MDN glossary: Preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request).

Comment: @BoristheSpider - the former case (and they didn't need to)

Comment: @Jesper I am assuming it was a preflight request, because for every GET request I sent to the `localhost:8080`, the LOGGER will log `* Connection accepted` twice. I am confused why a GET request would send 2 requests to the server, both Postman and the browser does.

Comment: It depends on how you're sending the request. If you make a GET request from the URL bar there's no pre-flight, because it's not an XHR request. If you make the request via something fetch-like (e.g., from JS code) it's an XHR request, and will pre-flight. If you send it from Postman it's just like a browser URL bar request; a standard GET request.

Comment: @Progman I am not sure this is related to CORS, currently I am debugging it why the client send 2 requests to the server. If you could shed some light, i am willing to listen.

Comment: @DaveNewton so, if I send a GET request from Postman, it should only send 1 request, right? While sending a GET request from a JavaScript will have a preflight request, hence 2 requests. I am starting to believe that I wrote a buggy code, hence it log the `Connection accepted` twice.

Comment: I updated the question to more relevant subject as `preflight` is misleading.

Comment: @kidfrom In general (if I'm understanding you correctly), yes.

Comment: @iggy AH. I see, TCP connection setup, thanks. That's why there are 2 requests, the first one is a TCP, and then the 2nd one is the actual request.

Answer (score 0):

Preflight request happens only in CORS (cross origin) requests - from one host to another.
If you had one you could have seen it in the network tab after pressing `f12` on chrome

Answer (score 0):

> . My current knowledge is that, for every request, there is a
> preflight request. In other words, if you send a GET request, it will
> send a preflight request first, and then send the actual request after
> receiving response from the server.

You are wrong here, not for every request, but for requests that are not "simple requests" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests

> My expected result: I can send a GET request from Postman, or at least
> I can see the OPTIONS request in the browser, but I can't seem find
> it.

This is wrong, because Postman is not a web browser. The whole contept of CORS is based on the idea that the browser itself will perform a preflight request, so the browser is the one that is curiosus if you beeing on the site X.com can actually fetch resource from Y.com. This is not forced by the server. Simple proxy configuration can totally supress preflights requests and any other cross site checks.

When you make requests from Java - you are in the exact same positin that the postman is. If you don't care about CORS, you will not apply it. To do it, you would actually have to make additional preflight request - which is a simple OPTIONS request with proper CORS related headers - and stop or allow future processing of the code.

Long story short - CORS is enforced by the browsers, not servers. Have browsers without CORS, and nobody will notice.

As an simple analogy, lets imagine you are a little kid, and your friend told you to take a cookie from the jar. Because you don't actually know if you can do that (because its your mummy's jar), you ask your mum if it is ok to take a cookie from the jar (preflight). If mum says its ok, you take it. If she says you cannot, you refuse to do it (proceeed, or refuse). If the cookie jar would be yours in the first place, you will not bother to as mummy (its the same site,  no need for preflight to ask for permission). Thats when you would have cookie CORS policy in your mind.

Beeing a Postman, you can simply ignore what your mum has to say, and just take the cookie - cookier jar will not complain in both cases ;) (postman case, java case, any other http client case)

Comment: So, why I am getting the logger log 2 requests for every GET request I send from a browser or from the Postman? (ps, thank you for clarifying about the preflight request, but I am still curious why my GET request send 2 requests instead of 1 request). The first request is empty though, I confirmed it with `inputStream.read() == -1`, it return true while the 2nd request have the response `RFC2616 section 6`. Is this a normal behaviour?

Comment: See the thing is that your code does not allow to accept more than 1 request as you have no loops there.